# Does anyone know the meaning of this EntryPointNotFoundException - "Unable to find an entry point named 'nonexistent_dummy' in DLL 'MSVCR80.dll'"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am interesting in understanding the reasons for the following FCE, always happening once when I run the unit tests of our application.

Note, that I wish to understand the reasons and fix the root cause, if possible.

The line causing the FCE:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current != null)
```

Exception details:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException occurred
  Message="Unable to find an entry point named 'nonexistent_dummy' in DLL 'MSVCR80.dll'."
  Source="PresentationCore"
  StackTrace:
       at nonexistent_dummy()
       at InitCRT()
  InnerException:
```

Call stack:

```
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.InitCRT() + 0xac bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.CModuleInitialize.{ctor}() + 0x2a bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.?A0x0b283f3b.??__E?A0x0b283f3b@cmiStartupRunner@@YMXXZ() + 0x2e bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>._initterm_m() + 0x44 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain() + 0x50 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize() + 0x8d bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize() + 0x42 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!<Module>.<Module>() + 0x2f bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Application() + 0xbe bytes 
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Csla.dll!Csla.ApplicationContext.User.get() Line 39 + 0x6 bytes C#
Csla.dll!Csla.Security.AuthorizationRules.CanEditObject(System.Type objectType = {Name = "LoginCommand" FullName = "Infra.LoginCommand"}) Line 829 + 0x5 bytes  C#
Csla.dll!Csla.DataPortal.Update(object obj = {Infra.LoginCommand}) Line 377 + 0x8 bytes C#
Csla.dll!Csla.DataPortal.Update<Csla.CommandBase>(Csla.CommandBase obj = {Infra.LoginCommand}) Line 336 + 0x8 bytes C#
Csla.dll!Csla.DataPortal.Execute(Csla.CommandBase obj = {Infra.LoginCommand}) Line 316 + 0xd bytes  C#
Infra.dll!Infra.SecurityPrincipal.LogOn(string userName = "admin", string password = "admin") Line 67 + 0x8 bytes   C#
Infra.Test.dll!Infra.Test.DummyEntityTest.TestInitialize() Line 250 + 0x1b bytes    C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunInitializeMethod() + 0x1b7 bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.ExecuteTest(bool isLoadTest = false) + 0xce bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.Execute(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestResult result = {run id {dbdf5dfd-2379-4adc-95d7-3ff261f3d4c1}, test 'OverwriteParentByReload' with id ffaccc31-77d5-45d7-ba1a-49c19dda3b4b: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Pending}, bool isLoadTest = false) + 0xc6 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestRunner.ExecuteSingleTest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter executer = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestResult result = {run id {dbdf5dfd-2379-4adc-95d7-3ff261f3d4c1}, test 'OverwriteParentByReload' with id ffaccc31-77d5-45d7-ba1a-49c19dda3b4b: MessageKind: Result, Outcome: Pending}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement test = {'OverwriteParentByReload' {5e89339e-d5fe-ce97-e001-a53a9505fe1e}}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ITestContext testContext = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext userContext = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext}, bool isLoadTest = false) + 0x97 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestRunner.ExecuteDataDrivenTestNotInLoadTest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter executer = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement test = {'OverwriteParentByReload' {5e89339e-d5fe-ce97-e001-a53a9505fe1e}}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ITestContext testContext = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext userContext = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.DataDrivenTestData currentTestData = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.DataDrivenTestData}) + 0x6a6 bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestRunner.ExecuteDataDrivenTest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter executer = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement test = {'OverwriteParentByReload' {5e89339e-d5fe-ce97-e001-a53a9505fe1e}}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ITestContext testContext = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext userContext = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext}, bool isLoadTest = false) + 0x10d bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestRunner.Run(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement test = {'OverwriteParentByReload' {5e89339e-d5fe-ce97-e001-a53a9505fe1e}}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ITestContext testContext = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}, bool isLoadTest = false) + 0x363 bytes  
[Appdomain Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter.Run(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.ITestElement testElement = {'OverwriteParentByReload' {5e89339e-d5fe-ce97-e001-a53a9505fe1e}}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ITestContext testContext = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.TestContext}, bool isLoadTest = false) + 0x73a bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter.Run(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.ITestElement testElement = {'OverwriteParentByReload' {5e89339e-d5fe-ce97-e001-a53a9505fe1e}}, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ITestContext testContext = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.TestContext}) + 0x3c bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.AgentObject.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.AgentExecution.CallAdapterRunMethod(object obj = null) + 0x209 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state = {System.Threading.ThreadHelper}) + 0xf0 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext = {System.Threading.ExecutionContext}, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback = {Method = {Void ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)}}, object state = {System.Threading.ThreadHelper}) + 0x111 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(object obj = null) + 0x72 bytes
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the nonexistent_dummy? And why it can't find it?

Comment: Excellent question. I would like to know it too.

Comment: I get it too. Any update on this ?

Comment: @haxelit Nope, still a dead end.

Comment: I have same problem when trying to open WPF window from non-default domain (unit tests are one of possible causes). Though, I can't isolate it from the rest of the app and on clean one it isn't reproducible.

Comment: More information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/wpf/thread/425df391-9796-4fb2-af0c-545b3977e2ab) stating that it is an ignorable first-chance exception.

Answer (score 0):

Report this on connect.microsoft.com I think you have found a bug in the .net framework!